# Set up an input box where the range will be pasted

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I watched this video on YouTube and it really helped me a lot, now I have to improve that code. So in the code where is the line for pasting the values I have to set inputbox or something else, to let user choose where he wants to paste it. Here is my code:

```vb
Sub IMPORT_DATA()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*xlsx")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets("NELT report").Range("R7:R14").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dispatch Monthly NETO").Range("L5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
        Range("L5:L12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question in your post (see [ask]). Also what have you tried with `InputBox` so far? Please show your attempt and tell where you got stuck or errors. The manual [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) might help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub IMPORT_DATA()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim s As String ' Range to Paste
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import 
Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*xlsx")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets("NELT report").Range("R7:R14").Copy
s = InputBox("Range to Paste : ")
If s = "" Then Exit Sub
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dispatch Monthly NETO").Range(s).PasteSpecial 
xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False
Range("L5:L12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 242, 204)
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks bro, its working, you saved me!